# Finding a button by visible name in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to pick (click on) a specific time on a screen full of times.  I've tried finding by PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT but without success.  Any thoughts?  I've attached a screenshot of the HTML.  I need to click on the button with the visible name "5:24pm".

element = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"5:24pm")
element.click()

[partial code on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFgfC.png)

Comment: It did appear the following found the button, but the click did not work:
#let's try to click on the actual tee time
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(),'5:24pm')]")
print("I found 5:24pm....I think")
element.click()

Answer (score 0):

Try to find this selector by css

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[text()='5:24pm']")
```

But more elegant solution is to use id selector from root that actually contains your time

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[id*=172400] button")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work fine:

```
#let's try to click on the actual tee time
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'5:08pm')]")
print("I found 5:24pm....I think")
element.click()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).